# Check in Shell if string appears more than X times in logs

Tags: bash, shell

I have a log file like:

```
135.148.41.73 - [11/Dec/2022:12:21:11 +0100]  - "-" code=400 upstream="-" req=0.449 up=- ua="-"
135.148.41.73 - [11/Dec/2022:12:21:14 +0100]  - "-" code=400 upstream="-" req=0.413 up=- ua="-"
135.148.41.73 - [11/Dec/2022:12:21:15 +0100]  - "-" code=400 upstream="-" req=1.001 up=- ua="-"
135.148.41.73 - [11/Dec/2022:12:21:16 +0100]  - "-" code=400 upstream="-" req=1.002 up=- ua="-"
45.87.212.41 - [11/Dec/2022:12:22:50 +0100]  - "-" code=400 upstream="-" req=0.004 up=- ua="-"
```

I need to perform some action if IP appears more than X times on the logs.

Using `awk '{print $1}' access.log | sort | uniq -c | sort -rn` I can count them, but how do I perform action on it using bash?

Like:

1. For each IP that appears more than 5 times in access.log, do something.

Thanks.

Comment: Why only in bash? Bash is the 'glue' giving you access to these other wonderful tools.

Comment: Because "why install 3rd party software to accomplish simple tasks" ? ;-)

Comment: Awk is not 3rd party.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

while IFS= read -r ip; do
    some_command "$ip"
done < <(awk '++cnt[$1] == 5{print $1}' file)
```

Replace `some_command` with whatever it is you want to do with that IP.

Comment: This seems to be the more simple and efficient way, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to do it this way:

```
for ip in $(sort access.log | awk '{print $1}' | uniq -cd | awk -v limit=10 '$1 > limit{print $2}'); do
    // Do something on "$ip"
done
```

Comment: See https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001#CA-7426c015cb48aa254a5e0fbecaef262728fa4b73_1 for how to loop on a commands output.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative form to the [answer of Ed Morton](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74761659/8344060), you can also make use of `xargs`:

```
$ awk '(++cnt[$1] == 5){ print $1 }' file | xargs -n 1 some_command
```

Comment: In my case a while loop fits better as I'll fire some commands on it. But this is a good option in case a single command is run.